# Unknown filesystem 'squashfs' when trying to mount snap packages

Tags: 16.04, mount, snap, squashfs

```
$ snap install hello-world
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core" (1689) ([start snap-core-1689.mount] failed with exit status 1: Job for snap-core-1689.mount failed. See "systemctl status snap-core-1689.mount" and "journalctl -xe" for details.)
```

Appears to be an issue with `squashfs`, I have run a test with `squashfs` to verify that it does not work in my `tmp` directory for loading a `*.squash` file with `squashfs-tools`. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and unsure how to enable support for `squashfs` or if it is possible. I'm running this on a dedicated server.

```
snap-core-1689.mount - Mount unit for core
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap-core-1689.mount; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-06-14 12:13:03 EDT; 2min 17s ago
    Where: /snap/core/1689
     What: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_1689.snap
  Process: 6092 ExecMount=/bin/mount /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_1689.snap /snap/core/1689 -t squashfs -o nodev,ro (code=exited, status=32)

Jun 14 12:13:03 hostname systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core...
Jun 14 12:13:03 hostname mount[6092]: mount: unknown filesystem type 'squashfs'
Jun 14 12:13:03 hostname systemd[1]: snap-core-1689.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Jun 14 12:13:03 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mount unit for core.
Jun 14 12:13:03 hostname systemd[1]: snap-core-1689.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

Comment: Who is your host? We've run into a few situations where hosts claim they provide Ubuntu 16.04 but then use a custom kernel.

Comment: @Kyle I'm using Kimsufi, I can see that in the advanced server install options there is an option to use the distribution kernel. This appears to be the problem.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Super frustrating, I'm sorry!

Comment: I'm on OVH and same thing seems to be happening, anyway I can check if I'm running a custom kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My dedicated server host was using a custom kernel which was the cause of this issue. Beware of hosting providers not installing the distribution kernel when they appear to do so.